Expression for change in orbital magnetic dipole moment
So, the question I attempted to answer from a physics textbook runs something like this:

"An electron is moving in a circle with radius $r$ and it has a mass of $m$. An external uniform magnetic field $B$ is applied to this electron such that its radius remains constant and the change in velocity is very small. Write an expression for the change in magnetic dipole moment."

I attempted to solve this question using the following logic:
when B=0, the electron has orbital dipole moment = μ
where I took μ to be 
when B-B, orbital dipole moment μB= iA where i comes from the equation B=iμ0/(2πR) and A= π*R^2
Lastly I μB-μ gives us the expression. Is my reasoning and working correct? If not, kindly explain please.
(P.S. I am rather new to the concept of electromagnetism, thus detailed explanations will be much appreciated.)
